# Find absolutely max value in 2D array c++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I wrote program for it but sometimes i get wrong answer. Please help me (x and y are index)

```
int main() 
{
int a[1000][1000];
int n,m,i,j,max,k,max1,x,y;
cin>>n>>m;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<m;j++)
    {
        cin>>a[i][j]; 
    }
}

max=a[0][0];
max1=abs(max);
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<m;j++) 
    {
        if(abs(a[i][j])>=max1) 
        {
            max=a[i][j];
            k=max; x=i; y=j; 
        } 
    }
}
cout<<k<<endl<<x<<" "<<y; 
}
```

Comment: Some indentation in your code would be helpful.

Comment: Braces for the loops would also help.

Comment: @SelçukCihan while I agree that having braces for non trivial loops is advisable, it is not the source of error here.

Answer (score 2):

You are not updating max1 inside if condition.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is somewhat unclear. 
Why are you bothering with absolute values? If you want the value with the highest absolute value, then you should update `max1` inside your for loop since you are using it to decide if you need a new value.

```
   if(abs(a[i][j])>=max1) 
        {
            max=a[i][j];
            k=max; x=i; y=j; 
            max1=abs(a[i][j]); //update the absolute value max
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    for (j = 0; j<m; j++
    if (abs(a[i][j]) >= max1) 
    max = a[i][j];
    k = max; x = i; y = j;
    }
cout << k << endl << x << " " << y;
```

}

change: if (abs(a[i][j]) >= max1) ------> max1=a[i][j]. you every time compare the abs ti the same fixed number max1 which is unchanged.